# Filling a Rectangle at different levels with Silverlight Animation?

Tags: silverlight

I am very new to Silverlight. I have a question on Animation. My requirement is, a rectangle should have different levels of  fill indication. More clearly say, my rectangle is half filled initially, it has to be either increased/decreased with animation. 
Can anyone help me out how can I do this in Silverlight animation?

Answer (score 0):

draw a 2nd rectangle inside the 1st rectangle. adjust the height of the 2nd rectangle to fill up/down.

now mark my reply as the answer.